# Regular Expressions - Picking the nth value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression, where I could select the cell with index 1, within row with index 3 of a table. I'm unsure of how I could go about doing this, especially with picking only that particular cell. I need to presume that I don't know what the rows or cells will contain.

The table is in HTML.

Please could someone offer some advice on this?

This has to be in normal javascript RegEx form, I can't use jQuery.

Comment: What format is the table in? HTML? You're likely much better off using standard DOM navigation methods (or, native querySelector if all your browsers support it)

Comment: It's a HTML table, it's a problem solving thing I have to do. I'm only allowed to use regular expressions.

Comment: If this is a challenge from a job offerer, reject the job. If this is a challenge from a teacher, ask for a tuition refund. Tables/HTML are very much the wrong domain to be using Regex for. If you feel you disagree, perhaps you could try to give us in more detail, **exactly** what the problem-solving task you've been given is? (Note: "You cannot use JQuery" does not by extension mean "You can only use RegEx")

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it very well. This is a question from a sample paper that I have an exam for tomorrow. This specific question asks for a solution using jQuery, which is easy. It also wants a second solution using **only** RegEx. I agree it's extremely stupid, but for some reason it's what he's asked for.

Comment: You can put valid HTML inside of tables that is beyond the power of regular expression matching, that is, HTML is not a regular language. Unless you give us some specific assumptions about what can be in the table, this is not a possible task.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's presumed it would be just plain text within the table cells.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is a catch-22. Hand me any Regex that he/she feels would find the target correctly, and I can give you a table that it would break on. (Oh, but you forgot to handle `<!CDATA` !) I still feel it's possible your summary of the question makes some assumptions, or misreads it, so I'd really advise you to analyze the problem closely. Perhaps they wrote "regular expressions" when the intented meaning was "normal, native javascript expressions"?

Comment: It's a question specifically related to regular expressions alone. I've already asked my lecturer about it, they're adamant that regular expressions are required. I don't think they want a perfect solution, just a regular expression that could get the some plain text from the field.

Answer (score 0):

This matches all the text in *every* cell. I'm working on the *nth* cell now.
Does not work in javascript because javascript does not support lookbehind. I know you want to do this in javascript, but that's flat out impossible. You cannot do this regex without lookbehind.

Assuming table of the form:

```
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
```

Regex to match the text in every cell is:

`(?<=<td>).*?(?=<)`

I'm thinking something along the lines of this:

`(?s)((?<=(<\/td>){cell index}+<td>).*?(?=<.*))`

but that lookbehind isn't parsing correctly, at least in Sublime's search tool.

We could put a number on the capture group within the lookbehind to specify cell number, and then repeat that process for  for row number.  Any suggestions?

More incoming.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I had the same problem and this is the first google search result.

Here's what I came up with (where `n` is the nth number cell that you'd like to match):

```regex
/(?:<td>(?:(?!<\/td>).)*<\/td>){n-1}<td>(.*?)<\/td>/gi
```

For the example given by @devon, above:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
```

If you wanted to match the 3rd cell (50), you could use the following:

```regex
(?:<td>(?:(?!<\/td>).)*<\/td>){2}<td>(.*?)<\/td>
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/YimYOr/1/)